# Restricting access to Lotus Notes databases

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

We are in the process of decommissioning some of our Lotus Notes databases.  Before we remove them from the server, we are wanting to not allow users to access the database at that point in time.

We are not wanting to remove the users from the access control list but wanting to shut down access.  Years ago, I had worked with an Admin who had done something that wouldn't allow users to access the database except the admin.

Can anyone tell me how this is done?  I am assuming this is done from the server console for that specific database, but I don't know the rest of the details.

In a number of our databases, the ACL is very extensive and we are not wanting to have to deal with re-inventing the wheel for restoring their access if they need to get back into the database.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Jean Stachler

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices.

You can prevent users from accessing the server by editing the groups assigned to the 'access server' and 'not access server' fields on the [security tab of the server document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/othr_serverdocumentsecuritytab_r.html).

If you need to do this one database at a time, you can mark individual databases as [out of service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_MARKING_A_DATABASE_OUT_OF_SERVICE_STEPS.html).

Comment: How is the database marked as out of service?  Since I am not an Admin, is this done on the server console?  If so, where is the setting to do this?  Thank you in advance for your comments and assistance.

Comment: Richard, please disregard the previous comment..... I did a search and found the answer.  Again, thank you for your comment.  I hate to see us losing Lotus Notes because it is so powerful, but it is a shame that IBM didn't push it more for what it can do.

Comment: I had linked to the relevant technotes in my answer. Unfortunately, StackOverflow's color scheme doesn't make links particularly obvious. I'm going to have to remember to call out links in my answers more explicitly.